# How to slide an element of a Slider by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, slider, slide

I trying to give slide effect to a slider elements by jquery. trying to Slide `h3` left direction, `p` right direction on this [slider](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html/). By default it has fade effect, trying to give slide effect only to `h3` and `p`, not to thumbnails.

*HTML:*

```
<span class="content-margin">
<p>This is p: famously orated against...</p>
<h3><a href="#">h3: Download Here Premium Templates</a></h3>
</span>
```

*JS:*

```
$('#headslide ul').cycle({
timeout: 4000,
pager: '#headslide .pager',
 after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag){
$(nextSlideElement).find("p" ).hide();               
$(nextSlideElement).find("p" ).toggle("slide");       
return false;
 }});
```

I hide/slide the "p" elements by this callback and it slide, but not from left/right.

Please See the Slider [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bacec898/14/) >>

*How to slide only `h3` from left and `p` from right?*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bacec898/17/)**

Add below styles to your respective `p` and `h3 a`

```
#headslide p
{
    margin-left: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    display:block !important;
}

#headslide h3 a
{
    margin-left: -350px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    display:block !important;
}
```

and this JS to `animate`:

```
$(nextSlideElement).find("p" ).animate({
     'opacity':'1',//change its opacity
     'marginLeft': '-=350px' //change its marginLeft to 0px by deducting -350px
},1000,function(){ //amimate with 1 second duration
     setTimeout(function(){ //set a Timeout of second
          $(nextSlideElement).find("p").animate({
              'marginLeft':'+=350px',
              'opacity':'0'
           });
     },3000)
});         
$(nextSlideElement).find("h3 a" ).animate({
     'opacity':'1',
     'marginLeft': '+=350px'
},1000,function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
           $(nextSlideElement).find("h3 a").animate({
                'marginLeft':'-=350px',
                'opacity':'0'
           });
      },3000)
});
```

> **The above 1 second and 3 seconds = total 4 seconds to match your 4**
>   **second slideshow animation**

Comment: Great, if slideshow animation is 8, then what it should be?

Comment: increase `setTimeout` duration from `3000` to `7000`. As simple as that! or it can vary on the combination to make `8000` like `animation` duration from `1000` to `2000` and `setTimeout`  duration from `3000` to `6000` and so on..

Comment: Anytime!! mark it as answer if it helped you so that others can find this question and answer useful!